# Перенос строк в ответах

Tags: поддержка

Я думаю, что перенос строки в ответе является отличным средством для примитивного форматирования текста.
Однако зачем-то он удаляется из тела ответа.
Два перевода строки вставляют пустую строку.

Например так.
Но чтобы начать новый абзац надо либо написать ручками < br>, либо лепить пустую строку.
Возможно я что-то не понимаю или делаю не так, но как просто начать текст с новой строки?

Comment: Два пробела в конце строки поставить?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Поставить в конце строки 2 пробела:

   > Текст
   >   и новая строка

   ```
   Текст  
   и новая строка
   ```
2. Явно написать `<br>`:

   > Текст
   >   и новая строка

   ```
   Текст<br>
   и новая строка
   ```

   > Текст
   > и новая строка

   ```
   Текст<br>и новая строка
   ```

PS: А двойной перевод строки создаёт новый абзац, что видно по увеличенному расстоянию между строками.

Comment: Каюсь, грешен, я не читал правила оформления и два пробела стали открытием, спасибо :)